# Java Completive error bank account class

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Update: Fixed the error by adding to the instance field. - Thank you.

### Second question: Could I make "activeaccount" a fluid variable and chance the actual account? If so, how?

When I compile the program, I run into the cannot find symbol "activeaccount" in the MainMenu method. I'm confused as to why I'm getting this error because I established the "activeaccount" object in the constructor. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

```
public class Account
{

  /**
  * Constructor for objects of class Account
  */
  public Account()
  {
    BankAccount activeaccount = new BankAccount("Seth Killian", "Savings", 500.00, 6.0, 0.25, 10000.00);
  }

  public void MainMenu()
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    switch (in.nextInt())
    {
      case 0:
       Initialize();

      case 1: //Check balance
       activeaccount.printBalance();
       SelectOption();

      case 2: //Make a deposit        
       double amount;
       System.out.print("Deposit Amount: $");
       amount = in.nextDouble();
       activeaccount.deposit(amount);
       SelectOption();

      case 3: //Make a withdrawl
       System.out.print("Withdrawl Amount: $");
       amount = in.nextDouble();
       activeaccount.withdrawl(amount);
       SelectOption();

      case 4: //Apply Annual Interest
       activeaccount.addInterest();
       SelectOption();

      case 5: // Print Log
       activeaccount.printLog();
       SelectOption();

      case 6: // Exits application
       System.exit(0);  

      default: // Unrecognized Selection
       System.out.println ("Error: Selection Unrecognized");
       SelectOption();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`activeaccount` only exists in the [*scope*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Scope) of the constructor. If you want to access `activeaccount` in other parts of the class, create an [*instance variable*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for it:

```
private BankAccount activeaccount; // the instance variable    

public Account() {
    activeaccount = new BankAccount("Seth Killian", "Savings", 500.00, 6.0, 0.25, 10000.00);
}
```

Or in one line (constructor can be omitted):

```
private BankAccount activeaccount = new BankAccount("Seth Killian", "Savings", 500.00, 6.0, 0.25, 10000.00);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're creating a *local* variable `activeaccount` within the constructor, that goes out of scope when the constructor finishes.

Move the declaration up to the class level and simply instantiate it in the constructor, something like:

```
public class Account {
    private BankAccount activeaccount;
    public Account() {
        activeaccount = new BankAccount("Seth Killian", "Savings", 500.00, 6.0, 0.25, 10000.00);
    }
    :
    and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BankAccount activeaccount = new BankAccount("Seth Killian", 
   "Savings", 500.00, 6.0, 0.25, 10000.00);
```

You are declaring a local variable in your constructor. It is only available in the scope of your constructor. If you want it to be an instance variable you should add it to the class definition.

```
private BankAccount activeaccount;   

public Account() {
    activeaccount = new BankAccount("Seth Killian", 
       "Savings", 500.00, 6.0, 0.25, 10000.00);
}
```